# I am getting an error when attempting to start my Azure Function App (.NET 8/Isolated worked model) locally (VS 2022)

Tags: azure, azure-functions, .net-8.0, azure-functions-isolated

I'm unable to get my Azure Function App to work in .NET 8.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using <namespace>.FunctionApps.Extensions;
using Serilog;

var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT");

IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("host.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"host.{environment}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();

var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .CreateLogger();

Log.Logger = logger;

var builder = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();

        services.RegisterServices(configuration, logger);

    });

var host = builder.Build();

host.Run();
```

I get the following Exception message when I hit the `host.Run();` line

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The gRPC channel URI 'http://:' could not be parsed.'
```

The function I am trying to run is a Service Bus FA subscribing to Azure SB Queue

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using <namespace>.Common.Helpers;
using <namespace>.InterimSolutionModels.Extensions;
using <namespace>.Models.DispatchMessages;
using <namespace>.ServiceBus;
using Serilog;

namespace <namespace>.FunctionApps.Functions.DistributionList
{
    public class DeleteDistributionList(ILogger logger)
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger = logger;

        [Function(nameof(DeleteDistributionList))]
        [ServiceBusOutput(QueueNames.InterimProcessing, Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")]
        //public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger(QueueNames.Group.DistibutionListQueue.DeleteDistibutionList, Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")] ServiceBusReceivedMessage message)
        public string Run([ServiceBusTrigger(QueueNames.Group.DistibutionListQueue.DeleteDistibutionList, Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")] DistributionListDeleteMessage message)
        {
            _logger.Information($"Received Message: {message}");

            var interimDistibutionListDelete = message.ToInterimModel();

            var outPutJson = JsonHelper.ToJson(interimDistibutionListDelete);

            return outPutJson;
        }
    }
}
```

My project file is as follows

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.13.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Files.Shares" Version="12.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.15.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Blobs" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Queues" Version="5.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="8.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="5.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="<Path/Namespace>.Common.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\<Path/Namespace>.ServiceBus.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\<Path/Namespace>.Service.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I updated the project templates and recreated the FA project in case that was an issue. I'm not sure if I missed a step somewhere (Azurite setup for example), if I am facing an issue from one of the libraries (I have found other places with the same parsing http exception but no solution) or I plain don't understand how this works yet...

What's getting me is that I am not using gRPC, so this has to be related to hosting / possibly my startup code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am getting an error when attempting to start my Azure Function App (.NET 8/Isolated worked model) locally (VS 2022.The function I am trying to run is a Service Bus FA subscribing to Azure SB Queue

Below is how I use Serilog and Azure Service Bus Function App:

**`Program.cs:`**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Serilog;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .CreateLogger();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

**`Function.cs:`**

```
using System;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp113
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function(nameof(Function1))]
        public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("rithwik", Connection = "rithcon")] ServiceBusReceivedMessage message)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Message ID: {id}", message.MessageId);
            _logger.LogInformation("Message Body: {body}", message.Body);
            _logger.LogWarning("Message Content-Type: {contentType}", message.ContentType);
            _logger.LogCritical("Hello Rithwik");
        }
    }
}
```

**`host.json:`**

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "FunctionApp113.Function1": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

**`local.settings.json:`**

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "rithcon": "Endpoint=sb://hiservice.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=chP9VP9/i7+ASbBs1ErI=",
    "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING": "InstrumentationKey=42f478bf99;IngestionEndpoint=https://centralindia-0.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://centralindia.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/"

  }
}
```

**`csproj:`**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="3.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**`Output:`**

After message is send to service bus queue then it is getting triggered like below:

[image]

Comment: I will look at this in the morning and see. (10pm here now).

I did note that when I commented out some of my DI registration (which did the log registration step), I got a different error about not being able to find my queue connection.
That made me think that my original issue was possibly related to Serilog and the App Insights connection and that I had not set it up correctly.

Comment: Further to my issue and the response above, I found that commenting out the Dependency Injection registration code I have fixed the issue.
Not sure what is causing it yet, but there's something in my library (shared code with my API) it would seem.

Comment: Seem to have narrowed this down to being in the register services. I moved all the registration into it

`.ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();

        services.RegisterServices(configuration, logger);

    });`


Upon playing with it some, I found it was happening when the

`services.AddSingleton(configuration)`

line is not commented out. Something to do with the config is triggering gRPC being added.

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/2121

seems to show the code triggering the issue, but I don't understand why it is being entered. Since I don't have HOST or PORT settings in my config, I get the issue it seems.